# What to do with outdated answers?

Tags: discussion, support

I was taking a look at the "First questions" review queue and was asked to review [the following question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29474/10454).

This question is a duplicate and OP even tells so, so I think it should be closed for this very reason. However, as also mentioned by OP, the answer of the original question is no longer up-to-date, as it is essentially made of links that are no longer alive.

I know that answers that tend to be "Look at these links" are discouraged (maybe for this very reason), but since a lot of questions are about some Quantum Computing frameworks, it is only natural that some answers become outdated at some point.

What should we do about such answers? For instance, [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13473/10454) (which is the one answering the original question I was mentioning earlier) is clearly not usable anymore. However, I do not know how to correct it. Should I flag the answer? Wouldn't it be a bit unfair for the answerer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to answer the question, I think the best course of action in such cases would be to answer the original question, or make the existing answers up to date if possible, and then vote to close the new question as duplicate of the old one.

If this is not possible (you don't know the answer yourself etc), then one could try to edit the new question to make it different enough from the old one to warrant a different post, for example by making it ask about a more specific issue.

This might also not be possible, if the OP is after the same identical piece of information, as seems to be the case here.
In such cases I think the new post should just be closed as duplicate of the old one.
I can understand people asking the question as that increases the chance someone sees the old post and provides an updated answer.
But the proper way to do this would be to edit the old post adding a notice that the information is outdated. A comment would also be fine, but the edit has the advantage of bumping up the post increasing its visibility.

Regarding more specifically what to do with the outdated answers: in the vast majority of cases they should not be deleted. Even if outdated, chances are they might still give some useful clue, or anyway provide some information of "historical significance".
As mentioned above, you can add a comment about the answer being now outdated, or also directly edit the post to add a notice about it, which also bumps the thread and gives it visibility.
It's also worth noting that questions with no upvoted answers get periodically bumped on the main page. This might be a reason why we might want to delete outdated answer, but imo it's still better not to. However, there might be an argument that downvoting outdated answers is a good policy for this very reason.

As an aside, yes, this sort of situation is indeed part of the reason why link-only answers are discouraged.